# .net core "dotnet run" command don't breake Azure buid pipeline (bash) on error

Tags: linux, azure, .net-core

Running an Azure (CentOS 7 client) build pipeline with a command

**`# Run DB migrations
 dotnet run --project $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/DBMigrations`**

this job is shown as completed successfully, although there was an exception
**`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`**
and I used

**`failOnStderr: true`** 
in my pipeline configuration.

Migrations code:

```
sing DbUp;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DBMigrations
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string ConnectionString = "Server=myserver;Database=db;User Id=SA;Password=pass;";

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = args.FirstOrDefault() ?? ConnectionString;

            EnsureDatabase.For.SqlDatabase(connectionString);

            var upgrader =
                DeployChanges.To
                    .SqlDatabase(connectionString)
                    .WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                    .LogToConsole()
                    .Build();

            var result = upgrader.PerformUpgrade();

            if (!result.Successful)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(result.Error);
                Console.ResetColor();                

                return -1;
            }

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            Console.ResetColor();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

*How can I make a job fail on error in dotnet run?*

**Update:**
.net core console application should write to Console.Error
`Console.Error.WriteLine(errorMessage);`to fail a job. `return -1` is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in

```
if (!result.Successful)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine(result.Error); // <-- here should be Console.Error.WriteLine(result.Error);
    Console.ResetColor();                

    return -1;
}
```

`return -1;` is not enought to break an Azure bash bild job with `failOnStderr: true`